# Launching a Java server from a Shell script

Tags: java, sockets, shell, shell-exec

I developed a Server/Client application using Java socket. My Server is Always Running as this code shows.

```
while(SERVER_STATUT) //Server Statut is always true unless the client launches the stop script
    {
        try {

            Socket sockcli = sockserv.accept();


        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The client interacts with the server and sends a message to the server. 
My problem is that I want the start and stop the server using a script shell. When the client wants to stop the server he calls the stop script. When the server is stopped he can lunches it again by calling the start script.

The start and stop scripts are stored in .sh files.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 interfaces.
One interfaces is for clients connecting to your server e.g. in port `8080`
The other is to receive the stop from your user e.g. in port `8081`
So you stop script would just send a request to the server in port `8081` to stop your server (essentially update `SERVER_STATUT`)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot write the full working codes for you, but I can tell some idea.

- you may want to take a look existing stuff, if it helps. `jboss/tomcat/apache...` start/stop scripts
- basic idea is, when your `start.sh` is executed **first time**, the script creates a tmp file (`yourapp.pid` for example) to store the processId. And if this file exists, it means, your server started already, you could display error msg if user starts `start.sh` multi-times
- also with that pid file, you could get the processId of your server, and kill it (not elegant way to stop the server) from your `shutdown.sh` this could be a `shutdown.sh -f` or `killforce`.  Better way would be, your server listens a particular port, to handle shutdown. e.g. storing some temp file, or do some pre-stop processing depending on what your logic needs.
- in fact you just need one script, say `myConsle.sh`, implement what I said above in this single file, and with "`switch case` like" structure, so that you could :

`myConsole.sh start|restart|stop|forcekill|status` to manage your server.

hope it helps